# Поле для ввода должно занимать всё предоставленное пространство

Tags: reactjs, react-native

У меня есть код такого типа:

```
<View style={test.textInputWrapp}>
  <SvgXml height={30} width={30} style={styles.iconLeftBottom} xml={storage.add_circle_outline_28} />
  <TextInput multiline={true} placeholder="Введите текст..." style={test.textInput} />
  <SvgXml height={30} width={30} style={styles.iconLeftBottom} xml={storage.smile_outline_28} />
  <SvgXml height={30} width={30} style={styles.iconLeftBottom} xml={storage.voice_outline_28} />

  textInputWrapp: {
    paddingTop: 5,
    height: 50,
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  textInput: {
    width: 'auto',
    height: 35,
    paddingTop: 7,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5',
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#E1E3E6',
  },
  iconLeftBottom: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginTop: 4,
  },
</View>
```

Мне нужно сделать адаптивное поле для ввода, чтобы оно максимально заполняло свободное пространство в зависимости от ориентации устройства